# How to automatically Left Align an image in html or javascript

Tags: javascript, css, image, html

Below is my code that has three images aligned horizontally next to each other.  Upon clicking each image I've added some simple action to remove the other images but image 2 and image 3 if clicked will still remain in their present area as opposed to Left Aligned like image 1.  Is there a way I can Left Align image 2 or 3 if they are clicked?  Many thanks

```
<div style="width:510px; height:105px; padding:5px;">

    <img alt="Passenger Vehicle" id="V1" src="http://hou-agsprd02/images/basictruck.gif" onclick="Vehicle1()" style="width:150px; height:100px; border:1px solid blue; float:left;" />
    <img alt="Water Vehicle" id="V2" src="http://hou-agsprd02/images/WaterTruck.gif" onclick="Vehicle2()" style="width:150px; height:100px; border:1px solid blue; float:left;" />
    <img alt="Rig Transport Vehicle" id="V3" src="http://hou-agsprd02/images/GasTruck.gif" onclick="Vehicle3()" style="width:150px; height:100px; border:1px solid blue; float:left;" />

</div>
```

Here is my code in another function that hides images 2 and 3 if image 1 is clicked, sorry for leaving that out.

```
 document.getElementById('V2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
 document.getElementById('V3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Comment: How are you removing them?  What is your javascript code?

Comment: @Axel:  sorry for leaving that out.  I just now added it to the bottom of my code/question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the visibility to hidden, which essentially hides the block, but still takes up space in the layout.

What you want to do is remove the space where the block once was, by setting the `display` attribute to `none`.

Based on your javascript code, you can do it by changing your code to this:

```
document.getElementById('V2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('V3').style.display = 'none';
```

After doing this, you'll notice that the block will be removed, and the elements around it will collapse into the areas where the hidden blocks once were.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Javascript code??  If you are just making the image hidden, it is still there.  You will need to actually remove the image from the page, then the images will fill it's place since they are floating left.

Comment: sorry, I just now added the code taht I'm using to hide the coresponding images